# How to query by nested data correctly for params.name='width' and params.value=30

Tags: elasticsearch

I have product items indexed in Elasticsearch where common information contains some parameters list (the list varies from 3 to 20 params based on specific product). Params has been indexed as nested values see products JSON example below.

```
{
"sku": "asd8574fdf",
"title": "Test product",
"params": [
    {
        "unit": "mm",
        "value": 100,
        "name": "width"
    }
    ,
    {
        "unit": "mm",
        "value": 60,
        "name": "height"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I dont know how to query product items properly based on params. For example how to query products with  'width = 60' .  When I do query like below this will find any item that has any param with name 'width' and value=60 but in even other params than width. Is there any way how to do it properly or index params in some other way?

```
"bool": {
    "must": [
        {
            "term": {
                "product.params.name": "width"
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "term": {
                "product.params.value": "60"
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

**EDIT #1**

I have nested mapping defined correctly but problem is that query above still finds product item as the above, because it finds item with name 'width' but match value=600 for 'height' param. The query like this cant say that value=60 must be for the param  with name 'width'. So it searches values across all params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your mapping contains [`"type": "nested"`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html#_mapping), and then you can set up your query with a [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) or [nested filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-filter.html). Be careful that you have the `"path"` parameter and field names set correctly. That trips a lot of people up.

To test, I set up an index with a mapping appropriate for what you posted here, and three docs, each of which have a nested doc with `"name": "width"` and a nested doc with `"value": 60`, but only one that should match your query:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "params": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "name": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "unit": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "value": {
                     "type": "long"
                  }
               }
            },
            "sku": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "title": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
"sku": "asd8574fdf",
"title": "Test product 1",
"params": [
    {
        "unit": "mm",
        "value": 100,
        "name": "width"
    }
    ,
    {
        "unit": "mm",
        "value": 60,
        "name": "height"
    }
  ]
}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{
"sku": "asd8574ghg",
"title": "Test product 2",
"params": [
    {
        "unit": "mm",
        "value": 100,
        "name": "width"
    }
    ,
    {
        "unit": "mm",
        "value": 60,
        "name": "depth"
    }
  ]
}

PUT /test_index/doc/3
{
"sku": "asd8574ghg",
"title": "Test product 3",
"params": [
    {
        "unit": "mm",
        "value": 60,
        "name": "width"
    }
    ,
    {
        "unit": "mm",
        "value": 10,
        "name": "height"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I can get back the correct document with this query:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "nested": {
               "path": "params",
               "query": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "params.name": "width"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "params.value": 60
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "sku": "asd8574ghg",
               "title": "Test product 3",
               "params": [
                  {
                     "unit": "mm",
                     "value": 60,
                     "name": "width"
                  },
                  {
                     "unit": "mm",
                     "value": 10,
                     "name": "height"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is all the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/2a299224da805e64932a2fec6990f2e173820b3b

Comment: The code that I showed you accounts for the issue you pointed out in your edit. If it didn't, it would return all three documents, as I pointed out in the explanation. Have you tried the query, exactly as I have it listed?

Comment: You query seems to be really working fine! THANKS! How is this working? How can I define params combination e.g. width=60 and height=30 ?

Comment: Because the "nested" query gets executed against the nested documents; so the bool must will only be satisfied if both of its conditions are met by a single nested document.

Comment: So there is no way how o create a query that matches multiple params? I tried to add another must:[] section to filter on other param but it doesnt work ...

Comment: Will you post another question explaining what you're trying to do in the second iteration? This one is getting a bit cluttered. I think there is a combination of query/filter clauses that will do what you want, but it probably belongs in another question.